# Object [object Object] has no method surroundSelectedText

Tags: javascript, object, plugins

I made a jsfiddle and it works there, but I'm not able to find a work around for my problem.

```
window.surroundtest = function surroundtest(element, text2,text3) {
    var c = $(element).parent().next('textarea');
    c.surroundSelectedText(text2, text3);
}
```

This is the code working on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmpY8/4/

It uses rangy plugin to place text in certain textareas. But when I tried to place this on my website, it doesn't work and gives me that error I set on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. had to use jQuery instead of $ for some reason.